# First $n$ digits of Graham's Number

Tags: big-numbers

I know using Euler's Totient function, it's easy to find the last $n$ digits of [Graham's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) (or any large repeating power tower), but is there any known way to find the first $n$ digits of Graham's Number?  How about in binary? Or in any base besides a power of 3?

Comment: Can anyone think of any other good tags for this problem?  big-numbers was all I could find

Comment: Finding the first $n$ digits is a completely different and much harder problem. Take a base-$10$ logarithm and you'll see that the problem boils down to computing the fractional part of the logarithm...

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/20765/the-problem-of-finding-the-first-digit-in-grahams-number

Comment: It will even be hopeless to calculate the FIRST digit of graham's number.

Comment: just the start number is already over $10^{10^{12}}$