# How are the first digits of these numbers calculated?!

Tags: elementary-number-theory, big-numbers

According to [googology.wikia](http://googology.wikia.com/wiki/Exponential_factorial), we have the following:

$$5^{4^{3^{2^{1}}}}=620606987866087447074832055728467\ldots$$

$$6^{5^{4^{3^{2^{1}}}}}=110356022591769663217914533447534\ldots$$

How are the first digits of these numbers calculated?  The last digits are trivial with basic modular arithmetic techniques, but I have no idea how the first digits are found.

Comment: The first isn't that big -- [Sage Cell Server](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/) computes `5^(4^(3^(2^1)))` in a second or less (the second apparently has too big of an exponent)

Comment: Lol, well that's nice.  I suppose we just brute force our way.  Any chance of a more elegant solution?

Comment: This might be useful http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/632751/first-digits-of-extremely-large-numbers-generalization-of-first-digits-of-grah

Comment: Programming wise it's easy to compute $4^9$, and $\log_{10}(5)$ is easy to compute(even copy from table)  to any precision take fractional part of $4^9\log_{10}(5)$ and raise 10 to that and you'll get your result like 6.2060...

Comment: @mrnovice Already saw :-)

Comment: @kingW3 I am so stupid!  That explains everything!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$4^{3^2} = 262144$$

$$ \log_{10}(5^{4^{3^2}}) = 4^{3^2} \log_{10}(5) \approx 183230.792816661313561889631182$$
so
$$ \eqalign{5^{4^{3^2}} &\approx 10^{183230.792816661313561889631182}\cr
&\approx 6.20606987866087447074832995296 \times 10^{183230}} $$
In a good CAS, we should be able to get $5^{4^{3^2}}$ as an exact integer with $183231$ digits: call it $N$.
Then $\log_{10}(6^N) = N \log_{10}(6)$ can be computed in floating point with a few more than $183231$ digits: if the result is $a.b$, and $c = 10^{0.b}$, then 
$$ 6^N \approx c \times 10^{a}$$ 
Using Maple with 183300 digits, I get 
$$ 0.b = 0.042796039418829008454171873916897558787404373143752795118675574544262$$
and then indeed
$$ 10^{0.b} \approx 1.103560225917696632179145334475344911419051187213486921746877175936
$$

Answer (score 4):

Actually, it appears this is not very hard to answer.  Notice that:

$$5^{4^{3^{2^1}}}=5^{262144}=10^a$$

We solve for $a$ by taking logarithms:

$$a=262144\log_{10}(5)=183230.7928166\ldots$$

Thus, there are $183231$ digits and the first few digits are

$$10^{0.7928166\ldots}=6.206069002\ldots$$

Though you'll have to excuse the accuracy of my hand calculators.  Likewise, with stronger computers, the first few digits of $6^{5^{4^{3^{2^1}}}}$ is doable by the same method.

Comment: That's quite a nice solution. Would I be correct in thinking it would break down if you added 2 more exponents on?

Comment: @mrnovice Probably.  The first few digits of the sixth power tower only holds because we have computers that easily evaluate $5^{262144}$ in full form.

Comment: See the marked answer.